# Gradle Java/Kotlin Force Annotation processor to always work

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, annotation-processing

In my Kotlin Gradle project I have a few annotation processors and one of them is designed to look into `resources` directory of the module and generate some code based on resources folder contents. It is something like R.java file for Android but simpler.

To trigger the process I found no better way then to annotate the `main()` method of my project.

But the problem is that Annotation processor works only when there is a change inside main method(obviously, because Gradle has incremental builds), but I need this specific processor to work every time something has changed inside resources folder, or at least I need it to work on every build.

No there are a few questions:

1. Is there a better way to organize this process - reading resources folder and generating some code. I mean other ways then Annotation Processing
2. If annotation processing is the only way to go, how can I solve the problem described above?

Comment: An annotation processor feels like the wrong way to approach this problem, resources don't have annotations. What you likely need is just a code generator hooked up to some resource processing task in the Android Gradle plugin.

Comment: How should I add a code generator to Gradle/Kotlin project? I googled a while but seems this is not a famous topic. E.g. for annotation processing I extend the AbstractProcessor and define my processor with AutoService, but how should I do this for CodeGenerator?

Comment: You can copy what SQLDelight (https://github.com/cashapp/sqldelight) is doing: it's connecting a code generator to Kotlin compilation tasks and generating code from SQL schemas.